# How to run an application on PC that uses crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have create an application using visual studio 2008 in C#.
That application can print a receipt using CrystalReports. It works properly in my PC, but when I publish this application and install it to any other computer and use it, It create an exception for Crystalrepot whenever I try to generate receipt.
What do I need?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to provide more information about the problem. What's the exception? What's the code that throws the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Hi bad luck for you but welcome in the world of the nasty, very nasty, horrible deployment phase for Crystal Report.

I got it working some years ago with VS 2005, you have to really create a setup project and include Crystal Reports merge modules then test on a clean machine and probably reiterate few times until you managed to include all the required components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the dependencies of the projects. You need to either ensure that any dll's being output by the project are being copied to the set up project, or you need to look at the dependencies/prerequisites of the setup project and ensure that crystal reports is included in the build (hence installed by the installer and eliminating your not found exception).

Welcome to the hell of Windows Installer. You may also want to consider Inno Setup to create your installer to make your life easier long term (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Both Crystal Report and RDCL need some redistributable package to work on other machines. Try to install this [package](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#09)